# Linq2Db / Access - error with anonymous group by multiple fields

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq2db

I have 2 tables: `pob` (with results of some activities) and `names` (with user data). I try to select top 5 users from table `pob` based on their last activity date. So I inner join `names` and `pob`, then select top 5 users based on calculated `max(date)`.

This query is working:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5
    [u].[id], 
    [u].[name],
    max([p].[date]) As LastDateOfUse,
FROM
    [pob] [p]
INNER JOIN
    [users] [u] 
ON
    [p].[id_name] = [u].[id] 
WHERE
    [p].[date] >= #2017-01-01#
GROUP BY
    [u].[id],
    [u].[name] 
ORDER BY
    max([p].[date]) DESC
```

Now I need to transform it into Linq query. This my attempt but it's not working.

`"Key" is not a member of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[VB$AnonymousType_2'2[pob,users]]".`

```
Using db = New DbContext() With {.InlineParameters = True}

    Dim query1 = From p In db.pob
                 Join u In db.users On p.id_name Equals u.id
                 Where p.date >= New Date(2017, 1, 1)
                 Group New With {p, u} By pu = New With {Key u.id, Key u.name} Into pg = Group
                 Select New RecentUser With
                 {
                     .id = pu.id,
                     .name = pu.name,
                     .LastDateOfUse = pg.Max(Function(f) f.p.date)
                 }

    query1 = query1.OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastDateOfUse).Take(5)

    Return query1.ToList

End Using
```

If I remove `.LastDateOfUse = pg.Max(Function(f) f.p.Date)` like below it works. By 'works' I mean there is no exception but of course result of query is wrong however grouping is done properly.

```
Using db = New DbContext() With {.InlineParameters = True}

    Dim query1 = From p In db.pob
                 Join u In db.users On p.id_name Equals u.id
                 Where p.date >= New Date(2017, 1, 1)
                 Group New With {p, u} By pu = New With {Key u.id, Key u.name} Into pg = Group
                 Select New RecentUser With
                 {
                     .id = pu.id,
                     .name = pu.name
                 }

    Return query1.ToList

End Using
```

### Edit

I also tried going through navigation properties like below, but again I receive the same error.

```
Using db = New DbContext() With {.InlineParameters = True}

    Dim query1 = From p In db.pob
                 Where p.date >= New Date(2017, 1, 1)
                 Group p By pu = New With {Key u.User.id, Key u.User.name} Into pg = Group
                 Select New RecentUser With
                 {
                     .id = pu.id,
                     .name = pu.name
                     .LastDateOfUse = pg.Max(Function(f) f.date)
                 }

    query1 = query1.OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastDateOfUse).Take(5)

    Return query1.ToList

End Using
```

And again if I remove `.LastDateOfUse = pg.Max(Function(f) f.p.Date)` like below it starts to work (proper grouping, wrong overall result).

```
Using db = New DbContext() With {.InlineParameters = True}

    Dim query1 = From p In db.pob
                 Where p.date >= New Date(2017, 1, 1)
                 Group p By pu = New With {Key u.User.id, Key u.User.name} Into pg = Group
                 Select New RecentUser With
                 {
                     .id = pu.id,
                     .name = pu.name
                 }

    Return query1.ToList

End Using
```

How can I transform above Sql query to Linq? (preferable answer in VB.Net but C# is ok too)

Comment: You seem to have tables pob and users not pob and names. Your error message seems to indicate you have `Group New With { pob, user }` and not `{ p,u }` like your code here shows.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the question. I made a typo. In fact `users` and `names` is the same table. This is because in database it is called `names` but in my code in dbcontext I have it as 'users'. So summarize problem is not here.

Comment: Your query looks good to me. Are you sure it is exactly as presented here? I was able to run it with no trouble using Linq to Objects and creating some objects to match the structure in LINQPad.

Comment: @NetMage I edited my question showing another way to error using navigation properties. Two examples, first with the same error trying to calculate max(date) and second without error and without max. I'm lost.

Comment: @NetMage I created quickly in my program 2 custom lists of pob and user class and with only necessary properties inside. I wrote a linq query like in my very first example using join. It worked like a charm. Conclusion? Either I have some error in poco classes (name conflict?) or in linq2db there is some error that will be impossible to trace. Up to now all simpler queries using linq2db were working. I continue investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

There is no solution yet. It looks like VB has bad Linq queries resolver - it creates unexpected method chain that can not be converted to SQL.

So instead

```
Group By ... Into pg = Group
```

we need

```
Group By ... Into LastDateOfUse = p.Max(Function(f) f.date).
```

See below full query.

```
Using db = New DbContext() With {.InlineParameters = True}

    Dim query1 = From p In db.pob
                 Where p.date >= New Date(2017, 1, 1)
                 Group p By pu = New With {Key u.User.id, Key u.User.name} Into LastDateOfUse = p.Max(Function(f) f.date)
                 Select New RecentUser With
                 {
                     .id = pu.id,
                     .name = pu.name
                     .LastDateOfUse = LastDateOfUse
                 }

    Return query1.ToList

End Using
```

### Another problem with lambda syntax

Using lambda syntax we receive another exception.

```
Dim query = db.pob.
Where(Function(f) f.date >= New Date(2017, 1, 1).
GroupBy(Function(f) New With 
{
   Key .userid= f.user.id,
   Key .username = f.user.name
}).Select(Function(f) New RecentUser With
{
   .id = f.Key.userid,
   .name = f.Key.username,
   .LastDateOfUse = f.Max(Function(g) g.date)
}).ToList
```

### Exception

VB.NET compiler adds unnecessary Convert to IEnumerable when generating Expression Tree.

```
An unhandled exception of type LinqToDB.Linq.LinqException occurred in linq2db.dll
Convert(f).Select(g => g.Date).Max() cannot be converted to SQL
```

### GitHub

I posted an issue [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/649).

Svyatoslav Danyliv based on my issue opened his own [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/654).